# Завершение выполнения потока thread

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как можно завершить поток thread при нажатии на кнопку btn? .interrupt не срабатывает.

Код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Some {
    static MyThread thread = new MyThread();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        thread.sw.btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                thread.interrupt();
            }
        });
        thread.run();
    }
}

class SimpleWindow extends JFrame {
    static JButton btn = new JButton("some_text");
    static JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
    static int count = 0;
    static Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();

    public SimpleWindow() {
        super("some_header " + count);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 400);
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        box.add(btn);
        setContentPane(box);
        count++;
    }
}
class MyThread extends Thread {
    SimpleWindow sw = new SimpleWindow();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sw.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: На всякий случай - делать setvisible можно только из ui потока

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thread.run();
```

Выполняет метод `run()` объекта `thread` **в текущем потоке**

---

```
thread.start();
```

**Создает новый поток** и выполняет в нем `run()`

---

Чтобы знать в каком потоке выполняется код, выводите название потока:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
```

---

Пример как можно сделать обработку прерывания для потока:

тело **run()**

```
try{
    sw.setVisible(true);
    while(!isInterrupted()){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());                 
    }
    throw new InterruptedException();
}catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Thread is interrupted!");
}
```

Comment: Выводит в любом случае main. В чем может быть проблема? Ведь вроде запустил через .start.

Comment: проверку делайте в теле функции run()

Comment: @Андрей а зачем вообще создавать доп. поток для одного действия (`sw.setVisible(true);`)?

Comment: Да, насчет действий, для наглядности лучше написать в run()
`while(!isInterrupted()){System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());}`

Comment: @Regent, учился, смотрел, как это работает. Знаю, что смысла в этом немного на практике)

Answer (score 0):

тебе нужно не прерывать поток, а вызвать метод

```
System.exit(0);
```

(выход из программы)
или

```
thread.sw.dispose();
```

(аналогично нажатию на красный крестик)
P.S. ты пытаешься "убить" поток, который давно завершился
для такой цели создавать новый поток не нужно